# How do I encode Japanese into something like "&#26085;&#26412;&#12395;&#34892;&#12387;&#12390;"? (UTF-8)

Tags: php, utf-8, encode

As the question in the title states.
I can't seem to find the answer with any of the following:
php headers, css headers, html headers, mysql charsets (to utf8_general_ci), or

```
<form acceptcharset="utf-8"... >
```

Really stumped on this one.

I'm basically going through this process:

1. Type Japanese characters, process through a form
2. Form saves in MySQL DB
3. PHP pulls data out of MySQL DB, and formats it for a webpage

At step 3, I check the code and see that it's literally displaying the Japanese characters.
Because it's doing that, I'm guessing it's causing the PHP errors I'm getting (the functions that work fine for English characters aren't working so fine for the Japanese text).

So I want to encode in UTF-8 format, but I'm not sure how to do this?

**Edit: Here's the PHP function I'm using on the Japanese text**

```
function short_text_jap($text, $length=300) { 
    if (strlen($text) > $length) { 
            $pattern = '/^(.{0,'.$length.'}\\b).*$/s'; 
            $text = preg_replace($pattern, "$1...", $text); 
    } 
    return $text;
```

But instead of a shortened amount of text, it returns the whole thing.

Comment: Just for the case you didn’t know: UTF-8 can encode those characters; so you wouldn’t need to represent them by using character references.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is? What PHP errors are you getting? What goes wrong?

Comment: I'd like the source code to reflect the UTF-8 encoding, not the literal Japanese characters (like, I don't want it to display "日本語", but the UTF-8 version of that).  And as for errors, I'm trying to shorten the text with a php function (added it to the post above), but it's not working when the characters aren't in UTF-8.

Comment: UTF‑8 can encode all code points, even those not legal for interchange such as all code points where `(cp & 0xFFFE) == 0xFFFE`, the code points between U+FDD0 through 0xFDEF inclusive, and the surrogates. Plus the UTF‑8 algorithm is extensible for code points beyond 0x10FFFF.

Comment: "I don't want it to display "日本語", but the UTF-8 version of that" <-- What is this supposed to mean? UTF-8 is a method of encoding characters so that they *do* display properly.

Comment: @Jeff maybe it's me, but I still don't understand the problem - if you have a UTF-8 encoded form, and you post it and echo the characters, they are going to be the literal japanese characters. What other result do you expect?

Comment: With “UTF-8 version” you mean the character references like `&#26085;` or what?

Comment: If @Gumbo is right about what you're looking for, see the implementation in [the first note on utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php).

Comment: @Jay I’m of two minds on literal Unicode. I strongly prefer real characters, not anonymous numeric code points. I don’t believe it absolutely necessary to keep source code in ASCII in a Unicode world. That argues for `"日本語"` in favor of the likes of `"\x{65E5}\x{672C}\x{8A9E}"` or `"\N{U+65E5.672C.8A9E}"`. Alas there are subtle issues one can miss that way, since it becomes hard to distinguish NFD from NFC forms. Still, I much dislike magic numbers, so a better solution is **named characters** like `"\N{HYPHEN}"` — which’s a bit lame w/unnamed Han codepoints: `"\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-65E5}"`

Comment: Your question is not how to encode them as UTF‐8, but rather as abstract Unicode entities expressed as ASCII.  Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: As “&#26085;&#26412;&#12395;&#34892;&#12387;&#12390;"

Comment: And it's not like I want abstract entities - it's because the straight-up Japanese characters don't work with the function I posted above.  I also get funky characters when saved in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Jay: Now that was quite clear!

Comment: `"&#26085;"` and `"&#x65E5"` both certainly specify an abstract entity. As for your problem with your function, are you somehow handling the string in byte-mode instead of character-mode? That would mess up no end of things.

Comment: @tchrist how do I find out if the function's handling the string in byte-mode or character-mode?

Comment: @Jay: I don’t know the “official” way, but empirically you might try determining the length of four literal strings each having a single code point respectively from the ranges 0—0x7F, 0x80–0xFF, 0x100–0xFFFF, and 0x10000–0x10FFFF. All should report a length of 1. Another way might be testing the pattern `/\A.\z/` against each of those four one-character strings: it should always test true when matched against them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of a confusion about what UTF8 **is**: by stating the goal as getting the "UTF8 version" of literal Japanese characters.

Things like `&#26085;` are ASCII-compatible HTML entities (basically Unicode references) already represented in some encoding whereas UTF8 is a multibyte encoding scheme that defines how characters are stored on the byte level.

I suggest relying on the literal form since it makes the whole mess with international alphabets easier to manage.

Simply migrate to UTF8 everywhere: in the database, in HTML, in PHP and in file types. Then it would be possible to use the PHP [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension which is designed to handle multibyte characters:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

function short_text_jap($text, $length=300) {
    return mb_strlen($text) > $length ? mb_substr($text, 0, $length) : $text;
}

echo short_text_jap('日本語', 2); // outputs 日本
```

Comment: It really is a shame that PHP does not support abstract character strings so you don’t have to think about such petty concerns as mb_this and mb_that. There’s a serious design flaw here.

Comment: You totally nailed it man!  Thanks so much!!  A question though about mb_internal_encoding - does this mean I should just set that function as a part of my entire website (like stick it permanently in the header)?  Will it hurt any of my other data (like English-based language stuff)?  Slow anything down etc?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, mb_internal_encoding should be a part of the entire website. It won't hurt other data as long as it's English since ASCII is a subset of UTF8.

Answer (score 5):

As you seem to want to convert your UTF-8 encoded string to ASCII and non-ASCII characters to character references, you can use [PHP’s multi-byte string functions](http://php.net/ref.mbstring) to do so:

```
mb_substitute_character('entity');
$str = '日本語';  // UTF-8 encoded string
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'US-ASCII', 'UTF-8');
```

The output is:

```
&#x65E5;&#x672C;&#x8A9E;
```

Comment: That looks good, but I’m still worried about his trouble getting his functions to work right on code points above the ASCII range. I don’t know why they would fail on his own functions but work on yours.